# Finding what child the nested ul is based on link clicked inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a setup like this

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#">link</a> 
       <ul>
         <li> <a href="#">link</a>
         <ul> ... etc
       </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So several nested uls, I need to figure out some way to find what level of nesting the ul has based on link that was clicked inside it, is it a top (1st) middle (2nd) etc.. one

Comment: @leo.fcx nth-children from container that these are inside, doing some stuff through .parents.eq(n), but didn't figure it out :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have clicked element `<li>` (in your event handler) you can just count all parent `<ul>` elements

```
element.parents('ul').length
```

Comment: I have a setup where I'd rather check this through link

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What you have to setup and by which link you want to check it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$("a").click(function(){
  alert($(this).parents("ul").length);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/81/)